custom bootswatch color depending on light or dark color mode
I am using a bootswatch theme, combined with dark light color modes from bootstrap 5.3.
I would like to run a sass build so that I have two different primary colors. One for light and another for dark. In the bootswatch theme directory, I've found only one _variables.scss file.
Does anyone know how to add a switch like that?
I can overwrite css classe via
@include color-mode(dark) {
  .bs-class


But I think it would be better to change the sass variables. I could build two css files, one for dark and another for light, but I think this somehow breaks the idea of a color mode.

I think you can use CSS variables along with media queries to detect the color scheme:
:root {
  --primary-color: #fff;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  :root {
    --primary-color: #000;
  }
}

And then you can use it directly:
.element {
  color: var(--primary-color);
}

or override some variables:
$primary-color: var(--primary-color);

